# Hittest and UIView Animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, hittest

I am using `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

to call a method to animatedly dismiss a view.

My dismiss method animates perfectly when called directly but not from within hittest.

I've even tried to ensure the dismiss is called on the main thread using this:

```
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

inside the hittest method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone any ideas on this, is there no inherent restriction on calling Uiview animation blocks from hittest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called dismiss method in touched ended, with `performSelectorOnMainThread`. issue solved.